Pandas Python Resample Interpolate produces just NaN
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Date": ["2016-01", "2017-01", "2018-01"],
    "In Vitro Diagnostics": [10, 15, 20]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m')

# Setting 'Date' as the index
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Resampling the data to monthly frequency and interpolating the values
df = df.resample('M').interpolate()
# df = df.resample('M').ffill() # works

# Converting the DateTimeIndex to PeriodIndex
df.index = df.index.to_period('M')
print(df)

Why does this produce only NaN, while ffill works as expected? How to fix this? I just want to linearly interpolate yearly values to monthly values

Your ffill works since it internally keeps the original values, while interpolate will reindex with the end of the month and lose your original values.

Use resample('MS')
Since you original dates are the first on the month, you should use MS (Month Start) as frequency.
df = df.resample('MS').interpolate()
df.index = df.index.to_period('M')

Note that M is deprecated anyway, it should now be replaced with the more explicit ME (Month End)
Output:
         In Vitro Diagnostics
Date                         
2016-01             10.000000
2016-02             10.416667
2016-03             10.833333
2016-04             11.250000
2016-05             11.666667
2016-06             12.083333
2016-07             12.500000
2016-08             12.916667
2016-09             13.333333
2016-10             13.750000
2016-11             14.166667
2016-12             14.583333
2017-01             15.000000
2017-02             15.416667
2017-03             15.833333
2017-04             16.250000
2017-05             16.666667
2017-06             17.083333
2017-07             17.500000
2017-08             17.916667
2017-09             18.333333
2017-10             18.750000
2017-11             19.166667
2017-12             19.583333
2018-01             20.000000

Why are ffill and interpolate behaving differently?
This is due to a difference in the internals of resample.
When you call resample, this creates a DatetimeIndexResampler object, its ffill and interpolate methods call an internal _upsample method with a slight difference.
In the case of DatetimeIndexResampler.ffill (source) the call is direct, and _upsample is performing the transformation:
return self._upsample("ffill", limit=limit)

While, for DatetimeIndexResampler.interpolate (source), this first calls asfreq, then interpolates. But since asfreq reindexes your data with a Month End frequency, you end up with NaNs before it evens has a chance to interpolate:
result = self._upsample("asfreq")
return result.interpolate(...)


Use MS (month start) instead of ME (month end) frequency:

FutureWarning: 'M' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, please use 'ME' instead.

df = df.resample('MS').interpolate()
df.index = df.index.to_period('M')

print(df)
         In Vitro Diagnostics
Date                         
2016-01             10.000000
2016-02             10.416667
2016-03             10.833333
2016-04             11.250000
2016-05             11.666667
2016-06             12.083333
2016-07             12.500000
2016-08             12.916667
2016-09             13.333333
2016-10             13.750000
2016-11             14.166667
2016-12             14.583333
2017-01             15.000000
2017-02             15.416667
2017-03             15.833333
2017-04             16.250000
2017-05             16.666667
2017-06             17.083333
2017-07             17.500000
2017-08             17.916667
2017-09             18.333333
2017-10             18.750000
2017-11             19.166667
2017-12             19.583333
2018-01             20.000000


resampling with a period index is no longer supported
